# suggest a current booster circuit DC-DC 1uA to 3mA

Tags: power-supply, current, dc-dc-converter

I have a source of power which can provide up to 1.2uA at 1.5 V DC, however, I would like to power a circuit which uses 3 mA at 0.6 V DC. What would be the easiest way to do this? Is this even possible to achieve this kind of circuitry?

Answer (score 1):

**No, this is not possible:**

The power you have is: 1.2 uA * 1.5 V = 1.8 uWatt (1.8 micro Watt = 0.0000018 Watt)

The power you need is: 3 mA * 0.6 V = 1.8 mWatt (1.8 milli Watt = 0.0018 Watt)

So you need 0.0018 / 0.0000018 = 1000 times more than you have.

It is like buying something which costs $ 1000 but you only have $ 1.

Comment: If you can wait 1000 seconds, and only need to operate your load for 1 second, then you could store energy in a small battery or large capacitor.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it?If possible tell me what value of capacitors should I use and how to switch the cap from 1.2uA, 1.5vDC power supply to the load?